# React Relay & React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

Doest Relay already support React hooks? On this video published by Facebook I've noticed a `useFragment` hook, but couldn't find it anywhere else, nothing in docs or source code.

https://developers.facebook.com/videos/2019/building-the-new-facebookcom-with-react-graphql-and-relay/

Comment: well, it is part of [relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/prerequisites), as I understood it is supposed to be part of  `fragment container` maybe they replaced the name with `createFragmentContainer`

Comment: `createFragmentContainer` is HOC which does the same thing, just in slightly different way. I was wondering, if there is a version of react-relay with hooks

Comment: Someone has started a relay-hooks library

https://github.com/relay-tools/relay-hooks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm from the Relay team; we're currently experimenting with Hooks APIs for Relay internally to make sure they work well before we release them, so they are not available in open source yet.

We'll keep the community posted when we release them in open source.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the Relay Hooks API is starting to be made public: https://relay.dev/docs/en/experimental/api-reference.